# GetProcessImageFileName not linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Im trying to use GetProcessImageFileName. I have included Psapi.h but when i try ti compile i get

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetProcessImageFileNameA@12 referenced in function "bool __cdecl FindProcesses(char const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > *)" (?FindProcesses@@YA_NPBDPAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)99>G:\Test\main\Tests.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

The function comes up in Itellisense so can anyone tell me why it wont compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a linker failure (it does compile) and is unrelated to the inclusion of `Psapi.h`. You *probably* need to link with `Psapi.lib`.

For specific instructions on what library to link with see the *Library* section from the [`GetProcessImageFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference page:

```
Kernel32.lib on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2; 
Psapi.lib (if PSAPI_VERSION=1) on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2; 
Psapi.lib on Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003,
and Windows XP
```